# Gtk3: GtkImage prevents user from shrinking the window

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Gtk3 in C: I am trying to create a window that loads a picture from a png/jpeg file. I want the user to be able to resize the window and automatically scale the picture to fit the window.

So here is what I do:

```c
  app = gtk_application_new("foo", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
```

then the `activate` method does:

```c
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new(app);

  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "foo");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 600, 600);

  GError *err = NULL;

  // Note: original and image are global variables, because I can't
  // get user_data for callbacks working. Will sort this out later.
  original = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("myfile.png", &err);
  if (err != NULL) {
    fatalf(scope, "Unable to read file: %s\n", err->message);
    exit(1);
  }

  image = gtk_image_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "configure-event", G_CALLBACK(resize_picture), NULL);
```

and the `resize_picture`:

```
  gint w, h;
  gtk_window_get_size(window, &w, &h);
  GdkPixbuf *resized = gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple(original, w, h, GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR);
  gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(image, resized);
```

Now the problem is that the `GtkImage` appears to impose the minimum size on the window. I can enlarge the window, which scales up the picture, but I cannot shrink it. Is there some property I can set on `GtkWindow` or `GtkImage` to allow me to do that? Or do I need to use something else than `GtkImage`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to switch to GTK4 and use `GtkPicture` instead of `GtkImage`.

`GtkPicture` has `can_shrink` property, which solves this problem.